# Dynamically loading fonts using Titanium SDK

Tags: javascript, sdk, fonts, titanium, appcelerator

Ok so I've got a rather complex setup for my Titanium app, but basically I'm creating a page dynamically by reading properties of a JSON manifest file that will be loaded from a server.

The app reads different properties, one of which is an array of objects that describe views on the page. For each object in that array, a view will be created using the properties specified within that object.

**I want to be able to change the design of the page easily, so that JSON manifest would also specify a font that the page should use.** The location of the font file on the server would be shown in the manifest, and the app will save that file for access later. How do I use this font file? I've seen the example on TutsPlus on how to incorporate a custom font, but that method was static. How can I dynamically load fonts for use in a view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Looks like you'll have to use a custom extension. No problem, someone has made this very easy!](https://github.com/dbankier/TiDynamicFont)

Answer (score 0):

I would try to create a webview to use remote fonts dynamically.

When you want to use custom fonts for assigning to labels then you have to package them into the app resources. This directory is read-only at runtime, as far as I know, so it would be difficult to download a font as a file first and then integrate it into the app resources before using it, even with the TiDynamicFont module.

Comment: I would assume I can load the font into the Documents directory and read from there?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake! Maybe you can load a font into Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory and access it from there. You have to try if the module will handle it.

Answer (score -1):

Related to your question:

[Display Custom Font In Tatanium](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/appcelerator/titanium-mobile-custom-font/)

Hope, it will be helpful to you.